# How do I get a line break in a Visualforce page IF formula?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, line-break

I've looked through various questions but still haven't found an answer. I have 5 fields that I can display on a VF pdf page and want each one on a different line, but if the IF fails, I don't want a blank line, so can't just put a br at the end. It needs to be inside the IF success part where I currently have & '   '. Please help!

```
            {!IF(activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.DementiaBeds__c > 0,'Dementia beds: ' & TEXT(activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.DementiaBeds__c) & '  ','')}&nbsp;
            {!IF(activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.HospitalBeds__c > 0,'Hospital beds: ' & TEXT(activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.HospitalBeds__c) & '  ','')}&nbsp;
            {!IF(activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.VillageBeds__c > 0,'Village beds: ' & TEXT(activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.VillageBeds__c),'')}
```

### [image]

**EDIT** <sub><sup>(from comments)</sup></sub>

If I add:

```
& 'BR()'
```

it just displays it as

> Dementia beds: 20 BR() Hospital beds: 42 Rest Home beds: 26

If I don't put quotes around it:

```
& BR()
```

It displays like this:

> Dementia beds: 20_BR_ENCODED_ Hospital beds: 42 Rest Home beds: 26

Comment: Just add a `BR()` inside the `IF(...)`?

Comment: That doesn't work - it just displays it as "Dementia beds: 20 BR() Hospital
beds: 42 Rest Home beds: 26 " if I include it in quotes, or like this "Dementia beds: 20_BR_ENCODED_
Hospital beds: 42 Rest Home beds:
26" if I don't put quotes around it.

Comment: Just edited my comment Adrian to explain both...

Comment: On the VF page you will have to use `escape="false"` if you are going to use BR() and are using outputText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to do everything in a large formula you can break it up into several controls.

Before:

```
<apex:page renderAs="PDF" standardController="Account">

    {!IF(Account.AnnualRevenue > 10,'More than 10: ' & TEXT(Account.AnnualRevenue) & BR() & '  ','')}&nbsp;
    {!IF(Account.AnnualRevenue > 20,'More than 20: ' & TEXT(Account.AnnualRevenue) & BR() & '  ','')}&nbsp;
    {!IF(Account.AnnualRevenue > 30,'More than 30: ' & TEXT(Account.AnnualRevenue) & '  ','')}

</apex:page>
```

After:

```
<apex:page renderAs="PDF" standardController="Account">

    <apex:outputText rendered="{!Account.AnnualRevenue > 10}" >More than 10: {!Account.AnnualRevenue}<br/></apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!Account.AnnualRevenue > 20}" >More than 20: {!Account.AnnualRevenue}<br/></apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!Account.AnnualRevenue > 30}" >More than 30: {!Account.AnnualRevenue}<br/></apex:outputText>

</apex:page>
```

Result:

Above the line shows the Before result and below the After result.

[image]

Comment: I prefer your way though as it doesn't use the "escape=false" (sorry @vorno)

Answer (score 3):

Pop it into an outputText tag

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.DementiaBeds__c > 0}" value="Dementia beds: {!activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.DementiaBeds__c}<br/>" escape="false" />
<apex:outputText rendered="{!activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.HospitalBeds__c > 0}" value="Hospital beds: {!activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.HospitalBeds__c}<br/>" escape="false" />
<apex:outputText rendered="{!activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.VillageBeds__c  > 0}" value="Village beds: {!activity.CallCycleActivity.Account__r.VillageBeds__c}<br/>" escape="false" />
```

Comment: You don't need to add HTH to your posts. That's inherent in your attempt to answer, that you hope you are helping out. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Good manners don't cost nothing do they, eh

Comment: Similar issue to [this meta post](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/is-tia-similar-acceptable-in-a-question). It's irrelevant information. Just keep in mind it's a Q&A forum. Politeness is good but putting some sort of signature on *every* post is just overkill and would get old really quickly if everyone did it.